# Ruby-Gnome2 Notebook color

Tags: ruby, gtk2, ruby-gnome2

I'd like to be able to dynamically change the background color a notebook page in ruby-gnome2 after the program has run. I've only found ONE way of setting the background color:

```
# Some page contents, for the sake of example
box1 = Gtk::HBox.new(false, 2)
box1.pack_start(Gtk::Label.new("Page 1"))
box2 = Gtk::HBox.new(false, 2)
box2.pack_start(Gtk::Label.new("Page 2"))

notebook = Gtk::Notebook.new      # Create a notebook object
notebook.append_page(box1)        # Create a page with box1 as contents
notebook.append_page(box2)        # Create a page with box2 as contents
style = notebook.style            # Copy the currently applied style
style.set_bg(Gtk::STATE_NORMAL, bg.red, bg.green, bg.blue) # Update the bg color
notebook.style = style            # Set notebook's style to the updated object
```

This is fine if it's applied before `Gtk.main` is kicked off. But it has no effect after the window has already launched. I've tried combinations of `modify_bg` and `modify_base` on both the notebook object and the page contents, to no effect.

Is there a proper way to set the color of a notebook page that isn't so hackish, and can be applied after the main loop is run?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is from 5 years ago but I'll give you an example of how I did it with the newest version of the Ruby-GNOME2 bindings. If not to you, maybe it could still come handy to someone else:

```
color = Gdk::Color.parse("#003366")

button1.signal_connect("clicked") {
   textview1.override_background_color(Gtk::StateFlags::NORMAL, Gdk::RGBA.new(color.red, color.green, color.blue))
}

Gtk.main
```

The button is able to change the textview widget color afterwards the main Gtk loop has started, if that's what you meant. Of course it should also work with a notebook widget.

I have to say I just started using Ruby-GNOME2 bindings and I am not sure this is the currently recommended way of modifying the UI appearance, but it works.